# Meteorjs build fails when starting the server

Tags: meteor, meteorite

[image: Error building the system]

Every time I start the server, the build fails. I don't have an idea on what keeps the build fail. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can reset the project files but whenever I try to start the project again, the build still fails.

Comment: Is there anything funky going on with `/media/Backup/Systems/`? Do you get the same behavior if you create the project in your home directory?